# Display results in a particular format MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
ID  Name Points
1   A     10
1   A     11
1   B     11
1   B     12
1   C     12
1   C     13
2   A      8
2   A      9
2   B      9
2   B     10
2   C     10
2   C     11
```

I want my output to look like the following

```
ID   Average(A)  Average(B)  Average(C)
1     10.5          11.5         12.5
2      8.5           9.5         10.5
```

The following group by query displays the output but not in above format

```
Select Avg(Points),ID,name from table group by Name,ID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your existing query in a subquery will allow you to build out a pivot table around it.  The `` `MAX() ``
aggregate's purpose is only to eliminate the `NULL`s produced by the `CASE` statement, and therefore collapse multiple rows per ID down to one row per ID with a non-NULL in each column.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'A' THEN Points ELSE NULL END) AS `Average (A)`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'B' THEN Points ELSE NULL END) AS `Average (B)`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'C' THEN Points ELSE NULL END) AS `Average (C)`
FROM (
  SELECT ID, AVG(Points) AS Points, Name FROM yourtable GROUP BY Name, ID
) avg_subq
GROUP BY ID
```

#### [Here is a live demonstration on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe79/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I'm trying it with m table

Comment: I don't know but for my table when I do the above it says Unknown column 'Points' in field list..

Comment: Just SELECT ID, AVG(Points) AS Points, Name FROM yourtable GROUP BY Name, ID works fine.

Comment: I know it worked in SQLFiddle example that you demonstrated. Of course my table isn't exactly what I wrote here but similar.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Very strange - if you have the alias `AS Points` in the subquery, it should be available to the outer query. You have given the derived table its alias `avg_subq`?

Comment: omg ! While giving Alias in the sub query, I wrote Point and not Points. I need to go back home now.. :-(. Thanks for your answer